# Python hang when reading data from C subprocess

Tags: python, c, linux

I have a python GUI which will open a C subprocess when started, and kill the C subprocess when closed.

The signal sent from python to C and from C to python is caught correctly.
However, there are some problems when data receiving at python end.

**Here's my program:**

**Python Code:**

```
fpi_c = subprocess.Popen(["./FPI_sig"],stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

def handle_inform_from_c(signum, frame):

    print("receved:", signum)

    outstr = fpi_c.stdout.read()

    print outstr

signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR1, handle_inform_from_c)

def gui_sense_and_save_fpi_2():

    fpi_c.stdin.write(str(123)+"\n")

    os.kill(fpi_c.pid,signal.SIGUSR1)
```

, where `gui_sense_and_save_fpi_2` is connected with a button.
When the button is pressed, data and signal *SIGUSR1* will be sent to C subprocess.

**C code:**

```
void signal_callback_handler2(int signum)
{

    int gpid;
    scanf("%d",&gpid);

    printf("Caught signal %d\n",signum);
    //fclose(stdout);

    signal(SIGUSR1, signal_callback_handler2);
    kill(getppid(),SIGUSR1);

}

int main()
{

     signal(SIGUSR1, signal_callback_handler2);
     while(1)
     {
        sleep(0.5);
     }
     return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

If I add `fclose(stdout)`, I could catch message `"Caught signal XXX"` printed by C at python end.

However, closing `stdout` make the PIPE broken and I could not send data anymore.

Without the line `fclose(stdout)`, program hang at the line `outstr = fpi_c.stdout.read()`.

I've tried `fflush(stdout)` after `printf` in C and `fpi_c.stdin.flush()` in python, but it still hangs.

When hanging, if I force the C process to be closed by task manager, I could caught the message at the python end.

Seems like python is waiting for the termination of C.

However, I do not want to close the C process unless the python GUI is closed.

How could I send and receive data correctly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally find the solution......

If Python attempts to read data from an empty buffer,
in this case, it will wait the input from C and hang.

There're two problems should be solved in the original code:

1. Add `fflush(stdout)` after `printf`.

   Otherwise, the output will be buffered and not actually written unless `fflush(stdout)` is called.
2. Python needs to know how many chars or how many lines it should read.

   Don't use `fpi_c.stdout.read()`. This will wait C input and hang. Instead, use `fpi_c.stdout.read(1)` to read 1 char or
   `fpi_c.stdout.readline()` to read 1 line.

Something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `fclose` the output stream, use `fflush` to flush it so that the contents in the buffer are written out and the parent process can read it:

```
printf("Caught signal %d\n", signum);
fflush(stdout);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. However, I had tried this way, and this did not work.